# React-Native, custom fonts option

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, styling

I want to use custom fonts in react-native so I created assets -> fonts and then linked libraries and it worked I can use my fonts. But now I need to add a new font to the file "fonts" and I cannot do that. Do I need to unlink the library? And if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Add new fonts to your assets/fonts folder then run `react-native link` that will work

Comment: Yes but I cannot add new fonts the assets/font folder

Comment: simply download fonts do you want and copy and paste to assets/fonts folder

Comment: I'm afraid that's what I'm doing but it doesn't work. The new fonts don't appear in the assets/fonts folder

Comment: Have u restart the IDE